# How to make object preview background transparent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to make object preview background transparent.
Is there any way to do this? I only want the object in the png and not the grey background. I'm on unity editor version 2021.3.1f1.

```
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR

        public static readonly string savePath = "Assets/BuildSystem/Data/Previews";

        public static string CreateAndSaveAssetPreview(GameObject g)
        {
            if (g == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Can't create preview for null object");
                return "";
            }

            Texture2D preview = AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(g);

            int tm = 0;
            while (preview == null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                preview = AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(g);
                tm += 100;
                if (tm >= 3000) //3 sec countdown
                    break;
            }

            if (preview == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Unable to create preview for object: " + g.name);
                return "";
            }

            CreateSaveFolder();

            var bytes = preview.EncodeToPNG();
            string name = g.name + ".png";
            string savePos = savePath + "/" + name;

            if (File.Exists(name)) File.Delete(name);
            File.WriteAllBytes(savePos, bytes);
            Debug.Log("Saved preview: " + name);

            AssetDatabase.Refresh();

            TextureImporter importer = (TextureImporter)TextureImporter.GetAtPath(savePos);
            importer.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;
            importer.spriteImportMode = SpriteImportMode.Single;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(importer);
            AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(savePos);

            AssetDatabase.Refresh();

            return savePos;
        }

        static void CreateSaveFolder()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
            {
                Debug.Log("Created directory: " + savePath);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
                AssetDatabase.Refresh();
            }
        }

#endif
```

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1601619/access-or-remove-background-color-of-assetpreview.html

Comment: Btw instead of that `while` you should rather wait for [`AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreview`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreview.html)